# Time Loop in VBA - Looping through Columns

Tags: vba

There are two sheets (sheet1 and sheet2).

Need to refresh sheet1 every 4 minutes as long as the workbook is open.

Then I Need to copy values from Column C in sheet1 to column C in sheet2 every 4 minutes.

Since new values would come in every 4 mins in sheet1, I want the values to be copied to a new column in sheet2 everytime.

I'm using the following code. The problem with my code is that the variable i is getting initiated fresh everytime and I am not able to initiate it to a value outside the module using Public i as long.

```
Sub copyvalues()
Dim i As Long
i = 3

Sheets(2).Columns(i).Value = Sheets(1).Range("C11:C90").Value
i = i + 1

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:04:00"), "copyvalues"

End Sub
```

Comment: Try storing the value in a cell and then referencing it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you mention you can't declare variable `i` as Public, this should work:

For example, the following works without issues:

```
Public i As Long

Sub test()

Debug.Print i

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Module1.test"
i = i + 1

End Sub
```

Try the following:

```
Public i As Long
Public SubIsRunning As Boolean

Sub initiatesubs()
If Not SubIsRunning = True Then
    i = 3
    Call copyvalues
    SubIsRunning = True
End If
End Sub


Sub copyvalues()

Workbooks(REF).Sheets(2).Columns(i).Value = Workbooks(REF).Sheets(1).Range("C11:C90").Value 

i = i + 1

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:04:00"), "Module1.copyvalues" 'assuming the sub is in Module1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. However it is getting copied much faster. In like 2 mins, it got copied 6 times.

Comment: That should not happen.. Try pausing the code to break the timed loop and rerun it. Add `Debug.Print Now + TimeValue("00:04:00")` to see the time it plans for

Comment: Now that I think of it, it is very likely you ran the procedure multiple times, causing the code to execute more than once per 4 minutes..

Comment: This is the result:

6/14/2019 6:14:56 PM 
6/14/2019 6:14:57 PM 
6/14/2019 6:15:24 PM 
6/14/2019 6:16:57 PM 
6/14/2019 6:17:00 PM 
6/14/2019 6:17:02 PM 
6/14/2019 6:17:04 PM 
6/14/2019 6:17:17 PM 
6/14/2019 6:17:43 PM 

Another thing that is happening is that when i clear the columns to run the macro again, it is not starting from Column C but from the column next to the last deleted column.

Comment: may use precaution so that file does not open from itself.. may use Before close event  to reset on timer  `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:04:00"), "Module1.copyvalues", False`

Comment: @KushalAgarwal that shows you ran the code multiple times. There are now multiple instances running after each other. If I were you, I'd pause VBA, wait for the first error and then click on `End` to stop all those timed subroutines from executing

Comment: @KushalAgarwal I have edited my code so that you now will only be able to execute the code once, so no more multiple loops! :)

Comment: Glad I could help you

Comment: @TimStack How do i select a particular range of values to copy (for exmaple in column 'i') while writing this: Workbooks(REF).Sheets(2).Columns(i).Value